# image uploading using Afnetworking is not working in ios8

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have done multiple image uploading in ios7. But it is not working in ios 8. I have shown my code below. Please suggest me what should I do?

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@abc.php", SERVERNAME]; [manager POST:url parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)  {
        for (int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++) {
            NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d", (int)(i + 1)];
            NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", filelist[i]]]];
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:imgData name:imgName fileName:filelist[i] mimeType:@"image/png"];
        }
         } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {  NSLog("getting response");      } Failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);

    }];
```

Debug point not comes in success part.
Can You please help me for solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Rob, When it comes on failure part it shows request timed out error. And I have also checked imgdata. It has values. Its not nil.

Comment: Very good. I guess I'd now resort to running this request with [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) under iOS 7 and again under iOS 8 and see if you could see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can used below code to get response from POST request

1 Add SBJSON classes in your project or NSJSONSerialization class to encode data

```
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"You -server -url "];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    // Server parameter dict

    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:txtUserName.text,@"Email",txtPassword.text,@"Password",[appDelegate uniqueIDForDevice],@"DeviceToken",@"ios",@"DeviceType", nil];

    NSString *jsonRequest = [jsonDict JSONRepresentation];
    NSData *requestData = [jsonRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: requestData];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSError *err = nil ;

         NSDictionary *dict=  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData :data options : 0 error :&err];

      NSLog(@"%@",dict);
     }];        
}
```

Comment: Hi Karan, Thanks for answering. But My question is I have an issue in Uploading multiple images on server using Afnetworking library.In this how to pass parameter for uploading images. If you have any other solution to upload multiple images using Afnetworking library or any other Concept. Then please share with me.

Comment: Hi Asha, Add the collection of images in NSArray and then convert NSArray to NSData  NSData * requestData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:<collection of images array object> ];
    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData: requestData  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Hi Kirti and Karan, I have tried with upper one solution. Afnetworking library has still issue in ios8. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this method

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

    NSString *charset = (NSString *)CFStringConvertEncodingToIANACharSetName(CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding));
    [request setURL:baseUrl];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";
    NSString *endBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary];

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; charset=%@; boundary=%@", charset, boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *tempPostData = [NSMutableData data];
    [tempPostData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



    for(int i=0;i<keys.count;i++){
        NSString *str = values[i];
        NSString *key =keys[i];
        NSLog(@"Key Value pair: %@-%@",key,str);
        [tempPostData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [tempPostData appendData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        // [tempPostData appendData:[@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [tempPostData appendData:[endBoundary dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    }

    //semd multiple images to server
    for (int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++) {

        [tempPostData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        if (i == 0)
        {
            [tempPostData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image1\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filelist[0]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [tempPostData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [tempPostData appendData:imageData1];
            [tempPostData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }

        else if (i == 1)
        {
            [tempPostData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image2\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filelist[1]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [tempPostData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [tempPostData appendData:imageData2];
            [tempPostData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }
        else
        {
            [tempPostData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image3\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filelist[2]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [tempPostData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [tempPostData appendData:imageData3];
            [tempPostData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }
        //        [tempPostData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        //        [tempPostData appendData:imgData];

    }




    [tempPostData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:tempPostData];
    _receivedData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: 0];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if( theConnection )
    {

        NSLog(@"request uploading successful");


    }
    else
    {
        _receivedData = nil;
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
```

It is working for me. It is working for Uploading Multiple images. And Afnetworking has still issue in ios8.

Thanks